# Splitting atoms with pipe symbols

Tags: prolog

I have a list of lists of this structure in GNU-Prolog:

```
[[1|5], [1|6], [2|6], [3|6]]
```

What might be the best way to extract the numbers in each sublist separately? I can't unify each term because of the pipe, unless there is something I am missing. Any help would be great; I'm very new to Prolog and haven't found much online for this issue

Comment: `[A|B] = [1|2]` will yield `A = 1` and `B = 2`. If you're processing the whole list `[[1|5], [1|6], [2|6], [3|6]]` and it's represented as `[H|T]` then you'd extract the head components by `H = [A|B]`. I'm not sure what you mean when you say, *I can't unify each term because of the pipe*. Did you try it at a Prolog prompt? You can learn a lot just trying things there.

Comment: You can also define a simple predicate, `separate([A,B], A, B).` you can call it on `separate([1|2], A, B)`, for example, and get `A = 1` and `B = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

Then I tryed this in console (SWI).
Does this help?

```
?- [1|2]=..A.
A = ['[|]', 1, 2].

?- [1|2]='[|]'(A,B).
A = 1,
B = 2.
```

I mean matching like

```
    [1|2]='[|]'(A,B).
```

will succeed.

Comment: Note that in GNU-Prolog, as in any other ISO-conforming system,  `?- [1|2] =.. A` gives `A = ['.', 1, 2]`

Comment: You don't need to go through all that. You can unify them simply with, `[1|2] = [A|B]`.

Answer (score -1):

Typically righthand side of the `|` operator should be a list(including empty list `[]`).
You should write like :

```
[[1|[5]], [1|[6]], [2|[6]], [3|[6]]]
```

or simply

```
[[1,5],[1,6],[2,6],[3,6]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm given lists like this as a test case, so I can't change how they're formatted.